# Why isn't my drag scaling in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dragging function in d3, which follows a pretty simple pattern, enclosed below. However, the problem with this is that it will set objects to go to pixel coordinates, and as such any coordinates that use the axis' notation will be treated as pixels. This can be seen in this test case: https://jsfiddle.net/gamea12/qzbhLe0d/

I noticed that this is nothing at all like what happens in [Mike Bostock's example here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708), in which objects are moved according to the axis. Is there any reason as to why?

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function (d) {
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        console.log(bbox.y);
        return {
            x: bbox.x,
            y: bbox.y

        };
    })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarter)
    .on("drag", dragmove);

function dragmove(d) {
    var barz = document.querySelector("#visual");
    var point = d3.mouse(barz),
        tempP = {
            x: point[0],
            y: point[1]
        };

    if (this.nodeName === "circle") {
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = nodes[1].x
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();

        var useZoom = $('#zoom').is(":checked");
        if (useZoom == false) {

            d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = tempP.x - xRange(d.initx)) + "," + (d.y = tempP.y - yRange(d.inity)) + ")");


        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In line 233 of the javascript for the fiddle, you are reading in the "x" property directly from the SVG DOM by writing:

```
nodes[1].x
```

This is in "physical" display units (pixels), as it represents the exact location in the SVG document that circle is located. Since D3's scales represent a mapping of "logical" units to "physical" units, if you want the corresponding "logical" value on your graph, you will have to run the "x" property value through the D3 scale you have set up, as below:

```
xRange.invert(nodes[1].x)
```

The "invert" function is necessary since the normal D3 scale mapping is one-way, or mapping only from logical to physical. Since you want the opposite mapping (given a physical value, what is the corresponding logical value), you have to use the scale's built-in invert function to do the calculation.

EDIT: Just to add one thing, the reason that you are only seeing this behavior in your project and not the linked example is that you are using scales to achieve a logical-to-physical mapping and display some sort of meaningful data, whereas the example is using purely physical units (or, it's not trying to graph any meaningful data, just showing a demo for dragging, so it can abandon the complexity of a scale and just deal with physical units directly).

Comment: @gamehen if this fixed your problem, could you select this as the answer?